# Fastest way to lookup a String value

Tags: java, string, data-structures, comparison

I have a simple application that reads data in small strings from large text files and saves them to a database. To actually save each such String, the application calls the following method several (may thousands, or more) times:

```
setValue(String value)
{
    if (!ignore(value))
    {
         // Save the value in the database
    }
}
```

Currently, I implement the `ignore()` method by just successively comparing a set of Strings, e.g.

```
public boolean ignore(String value)
{
    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("Value 1") || (value.equalsIgnoreCase("Value 2"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

However, because I need to check against many such "ignorable" values, which will be defined in another part of the code, I need to use a data structure for this check, instead of multiple consecutive `if` statements.

So, my question is, what would be the fastest data structure from **standard Java** to to implement this? A HashMap? A Set? Something else?

Initialization time is not an issue, since it will happen statically and once per application invocation.

**EDIT: The solutions suggested thus far (including HashSet) appear slower than just using a String[] with all the ignored words and just running "equalsIgnoreCase" against each of these.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [HashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), storing the values in lowercase, and its [contains()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method, which has better lookup performance than TreeSet (constant-time versus log-time for contains).

```
Set<String> ignored = new HashSet<String>();
ignored.add("value 1"); // store in lowercase
ignored.add("value 2"); // store in lowercase

public boolean ignore(String value) {
    return ignored.contains(value.toLowerCase());    
}
```

Storing the values in lowercase and searching for the lowercased input avoids the hassle of dealing with case *during* comparison, so you get the full speed of the HashSet implementation and zero collection-related code to write (eg Collator, Comparator etc).

**EDITED**
Thanks to Jon Skeet for pointing out that certain Turkish characters behave oddly when calling `toLowerCase()`, but if you're not intending on supporting Turkish input (or perhaps other languages with non-standard case issues) then this approach will work well for you.

Comment: On the other hand, that assumes that you're happy with lower-casing as a means of performing a case-insensitive comparison, which isn't always correct.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Isn't it? Are you saying that there is a case where `a.toLowerCase().equals(b.toLowerCase()) ^ a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)`? If so, please give one. To me, the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) seems to say they are the same. I'll be happy to be wrong here, because I'll learn something!

Comment: There are oddities in Turkish. If `a="ma\u0131l"` and `b="MA\u0130L"` that will give problems. See http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html for some more interesting information (.NET-based, but still relevant).

Comment: Does it make any difference if values are stored all in lower case, or all in upper case? I would guess it is the same.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Phew - I better watch out for those Turkish oddities! Much better to write heaps of useless code on the off chance that one day it'll matter... NOT! No offence, but that is a clear case of [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it).

Comment: @Bohemian: Well this has actually bitten me in the past. About 10 years ago I was working on a product and we had a bug because of this exact problem - using the string "mail" which I was trying to match. The product failed when running in Turkey, basically. So yes, it's a real problem which you *should* be aware of.

Comment: Back to the original question about speed: Isn't it faster to use a String[] with all the ignored words, and just run "equalsIgnoreCase" against each of them?

Comment: @PNS: Are you asking *us* if it's faster? This method will almost certainly be faster, but the only way to know is to try it!

Comment: I have tried it and it looks faster, as I just said, but this may be because of my data set, which is why I am asking for "theoretical" verification. This topic is about the (whatever) fastest method, since my original question was about what would that be: "A HashMap? A Set? Something else?" So, using a String[] does qualify in here, but no-one suggested it thus far, hence my asking again.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I appreciate your thoroughness, however for 99% of the world, the HashSet of lowercase is the weapon of choice. For completeness, one could add to javadoc that Turkish isn't supported, or better yet (since few read javadoc) throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if your input contains certain unsupported characters.

Comment: @Bohemian: It's not just for odd characters though - it's also that the *act* of upper-casing and lower-casing is culture-specific. If you want to always use the US way of upper/lower-casing, just call `toLowerCase(Locale.US)`.

Comment: @Bohemian: An example of what Jon is saying is that `"MAIL".toLowerCase()` will return `"maıl"` in a Turkish locale, so it wouldn't match with `"mail"` as you or I would expect. Conversely, `"mail".toUpperCase()` would return `"MAİL"`.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases I'd normally start with a `HashSet<String>` - but as you want case-insensitivity, that makes it slightly harder.

You can try using a `TreeSet<Object>` using an appropriate `Collator` for case-insensitivity. For example:

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
collator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);

TreeSet<Object> set = new TreeSet<Object>(collator);
```

Note that you can't create a `TreeSet<String>` as `Collator` only implements `Comparator<Object>`.

EDIT: While the above version works with just strings, it *may* be faster to create a `TreeSet<CollationKey>`:

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
collator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);

TreeSet<CollationKey> set = new TreeSet<CollationKey>();
for (String value : valuesToIgnore) {
    set.add(collator.getCollationKey(value));
}
```

Then:

```
public boolean ignore(String value)
{
    return set.contains(collator.getCollationKey(value));
}
```

It would be *nice* to have a way of storing the collation keys for all ignored values but then avoid creating new collation keys when testing, but I don't know of a way of doing that.

Comment: Does it mean the reference set should use 'CollationKeys' ?

Comment: @panzerschrek: Editing - I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Add the words to ignore to a list and just check if the word is in that list.

That makes it dynamically.

Comment: This is utterly slow O(n). It grows with time, he says the comparisons are in thousands.

Answer (score 1):

If using Java 7 this is a fast way to do it:

```
public boolean ignore(String value) {
  switch(value.toLowerCase()) { // see comment Jon Skeet
    case "lowercased_ignore_value1":
    case "lowercased_ignore_value2":
      // etc
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that String[] is slightly better (performance-wise) than the other methods proposed, so I will use that.

It is simply something like this:

```
public boolean ignore(String value)
{
    for (String ignore:IGNORED_VALUES)
    {
        if (ignore.equalsIgnoreCase(value))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The IGNORED_VALUES object is just a String[] with all ignored values in there.